# diffusion 6.2 C version - disable logging

Tags: logging, push-diffusion, push-technology

could anybody tell me how to change logging in the C version of diffusion? By default its set to maximum from what I can see. At startup my executable logs and logs to stdout/stderr, fails to respond to the diffusion servers ping and just ends up hanging.

If I redirect stdout/stderr to a file, my executable starts in a timely manner, responds to the ping and everything runs perfectly.  This is obviously not a viable solution.

Could anybody tell me how to disable/change the log level programmatically and/or by configuration? Again, its the C version of diffusion I'm runing.

Thanks much

Graham

Comment: The Diffusion C client doesn't have logging or a logging configuration. Can you show an example of the messages to stdout/stderr that you're experiencing?

Comment: Hi,

Sure, no problem. In the end it was the websockets layer (on top of which the C libs are built). 

POOL DEBUG: [PID/TID] ACTION  (SIZE      /POOL SIZE /TOTAL SIZE) POOL       "TAG" <__FILE__:__LINE__> (ALLOCS/TOTAL ALLOCS/CLEARS)
POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  GLOBAL                                    0xcb7c88 <memory\unix\apr_pools.c:apr_pool_initialize>
POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  CREATE (         0/         0/       148) 0xcbcb50 "misc\win32\start.c:194" <misc\win32\start.c:194> (0/0/0)

Comment: Yes, as you've correctly stated in your answer, the build you were using is the debug build of Diffusion's C client on Windows. The release build doesn't have this logging and should be the build to use for development.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found what it was...

The C version of Diffusion is built on top of web sockets. The debug release of diffusion for C has logging set to max for the web sockets layer. The problem doesn't exist for release builds.

I worked around the issue in debug mode by rediecting stdout/stderr to a file, thereby avoiding a ping timeout from the diffusion server.

Example trace output from the debug websockets stuff....

> POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  PALLOC (88/        88/       356)
>   0xcb78f8 "session:_root_pool"  (3/3/0)
>   POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  PALLOC (104/       104/       372)
>   0xcb78f8 "session:_root_pool"  (4/4/0)
>   POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  PALLOC (140/       140/       408)
>   0xcb78f8 "session:_root_pool"  (5/5/0)
>   POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  PALLOC (156/       156/       424)
>   0xcb78f8 "session:_root_pool"  (6/6/0)
>   POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  PALLOC (192/       192/       460)
>   0xcb78f8 "session:_root_pool"  (7/7/0)
>   POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  PALLOC (208/       208/       476)
>   0xcb78f8 "session:_root_pool"  (8/8/0)
>   POOL DEBUG: [10752/516] PCALLOC (252/       252/       520)
>   0xcb78f8 "session:_root_pool"  (9/9/0)
>   POOL DEBUG: [10752/516]  PALLOC (268/       268/       536)
>   0xcb78f8 "session:_root_pool"  (10/10/0)

Hope this helps somebody else out somewhere along the road...

Cheers

Graham WALSH